# Is it possible to assign a same property(bean property) for two different elements in html.?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, struts

I have a text box and a drop down box. Is it possible to have a same property for both these elements?For an instance i have a text box named "NonIndianStates" and a drop-down box named "IndianStates".

Is it possible to have a bean property named "states" for both these elements? I tried this but the bean property is getting assigned with the value associated with element which occurs first in HTML and the second elements value is not taken into account....

Comment: You're not even saying which framework you're using. What would be the point of populating a single property with the input from 2 different HTML controls? What's your end goal?

Comment: Ru very sure...coz earlier it was working fine for me..but when i made some java script changes this error started ocuring...

Comment: I'm using struts frame work... if user got to choose indian states im having them in a drop down...but for non indian states user must enter value in text box...once the value is selected or entered i will use this value in a common bean property called "states" and will store the value in DB. Now the problem is if i'm having text box as first element in html then the property is getting assigned with non indian states only...

Comment: That was not reply to you JB....some one answered this is not possible ...so i pointed them not u....

Comment: hope i have answered ur question as well...

Comment: Then show us your code, and tell us what you changed in the JS code to make it not working anymore But I would still use two different bean properties anyway, and create a joined list from these two fields at server-side. What if the form is invalid? How would you redisplay the form pre-populated if the select box values and the input box value were all in the same property?

Comment: Please answer whetehr is it possible to have one property for two different html elements

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't be possible. Struts doesn't care or know about your HTML elements. It takes the parameters of the request, and populates the form bean with them.

Comment: yeah, it's possible with the some attribute.